# Android browser that will load an SSLv3 page?

Tags: android

I'm trying to configure my router remotely, but its remote management features only uses SSLv3. Chrome and Firefox have both removed SSLv3 compatibility altogether (not even advanced config settings work anymore). The router has no remote HTTP option, so I'm stuck with SSL.

From a PC, I can load it with IE9 (although it complains). However, my phone's stock browser refuses to load the page, and, of course, mobile Chrome won't load it either. Is there a modern mobile browser that still supports SSLv3? I don't want to downgrade Chrome and leave myself open to actual attacks.

Comment: Question was off-topic at Super User: http://superuser.com/q/957471/131357